# servlet me redirige a pagina en blanco

Tags: java, servlets

Hola bueno estoy en un sistema bastante básico y es básicamente un CRUD, bueno es un resulta que al momento de validar mi "Agregar Profesor" este se va en blanco
y tengo otra otro CRUD de igual atributos y no tengo problema , es esto bueno dejo el codigo de la clase que llama a mi agregar  osea el validar:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    String rutProfesores = request.getParameter("rutProfesores");
    String nombre = request.getParameter("nombre");
    String domicilio = request.getParameter("domicilio");
    String telefono = request.getParameter("telefono");
    String correoElectronico = request.getParameter("correoElectronico");

    String asignaturaCodigo = request.getParameter("asignaturaCodigo");
    Integer asignatura_int = Integer.parseInt(asignaturaCodigo);

    String cursoProfesor = request.getParameter("cursoProfesor");


    Asignatura a = asignaturaFacade.find(asignatura_int);

    Profesores profesor = new Profesores();

    profesor.setRutProfesores(rutProfesores);
    profesor.setNombre(nombre);
    profesor.setDomicilio(domicilio);
    profesor.setTelefono(telefono);
    profesor.setCorreoElectronico(correoElectronico);
    profesor.setAsignaturaCodigo(a);
    profesor.setCursoProfesor(cursoProfesor);

    profesoresFacade.create(profesor);


    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("indexProfesores.view");
    rd.forward(request, response);
    } }
```

Comment: Agradeceria su ayuda

Comment: Me da la sensación de que algo falta en ese código porque no veo la parte del `catch` y/o `finally` que corresponde con el `try` ¿Puede ser que no hayas copiado bien el código o es que no tienes esa parte?

Comment: te refieres a esto

try {

} catch {

} finally {

}

? Lo que sí tengo ese mismo código en otra validación y funciona bien, de ser eso lo que me dices del try que me falta el catch y finally, alguna idea de como podría ser? Gracias de todas maneras Javi.

Comment: Parece que se puede dejar el `try` sin el `catch/finally`, otra cosa es que sea buena idea porque podría estar dando una excepción, con lo que no terminaría el código dentro del `try`, no te enterarías y no estaría enviando la respuesta. Es decir, ¿cómo sabes que está llegando al código del `RequestDispatcher` y no está fallando antes?

Comment: Te recomiendo cambiarle un poco tu arquitectura para incluir [filtros e interceptores](http://www.mkjava.com/tutorial/filter-vs-interceptor/)  así separas la creación de tu objeto de tu redirección que es donde creo que está el problema. Sin tu archivo `web.xml` es imposible saber si está o no bien mapeado `indexProfesores.view`, y sinceramente pienso que la terminación `.view` es algo sospechoso .

Comment: `indexProfesores.view` intenta direccionar a un `.jsp`, allí saldrás de dudas si es la extensión o la ruta. Un saludo